# Why was there a gun on the ground in this scene from Marvel's Eternals?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, eternals-2021

In a flashback scene, we learn that

> Ikaris murdered Ajak because she had decided to try to stop the Emergence.  He takes her to Alaska and pushes her off a cliff onto an ice plain to leave her at the mercy of the Deviants.

The part that confused me is that

> seconds after she lands, Ajak finds a loaded shotgun just lying there on the ice, which she grabs and uses to shoot twice at the Deviants (but it barely hurts them and she is soon overpowered by a larger Deviant attacking from behind).

Where did this gun come from?

> It's too big for Ajak to have been hiding it under her coat.  Did Ikaris plant it there for some reason?  Or is it just an amazing coincidence?

Comment: _"They killed an entire company of oil workers. I tracked them here."_ Presumably from one of the oil workers. However, he does say he tracked them there which makes it seem less plausible.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Shortly before Ikaris...

> ... pushes Ajak off the cliff...

... he mentions that the Deviants killed a company of oil workers.

> IKARIS: It’s just up ahead. They must have been trapped in the ice for centuries and broke free last week when the glacier started to melt as the Earth’s core heats up for the emergence. **They killed an entire company of oil workers.** I tracked them here.
>
> <sub>*Eternals (2021)*</sub>

The opening shot of the scene in Alaska shows some manmade structures you'd associate with an oil field.

[image]

This shot shows one of the Deviants tugging on what looks like a bag of some kind.

[image]

You can see some oil pumps near the top of this shot.

[image]

And there's a damaged snowmobile in the bottom-right corner of this shot. The snowmobile is also visible in the third image, near tracks on the ice, leading toward the oil pumps.

[image]

Given everything above, it appears that the spot where...

> ... Ajak was killed by the Deviants...

... is the same place where at least one of the oil workers was killed, and some of their belongings -- including the gun and the snowmobile -- were left strewn across the ice.

Comment: Thank you!  Excellent use of screen shots, too.